# STAthread doesn't let me print reports in c#

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have problem with my application. The application starts with login form then I'm using the following thread to run my application.

```
Thread t = new Thread(Program.RunApplication);
t.Start();
Thread.Sleep(2000);
```

but I have problem now when trying to save any of my reports as excel or pdf it gives me error
current thread must be sit to single thread which I made by adding

```
[STAThread]
```

before my Main[] 
but now I don't really know what is the problem.

Can anybody help please?

Comment: I'm sorry English is not my mother tongue. I think I didn't get what you exactly mean but I have Log in form starts then my user fill password & username then the program parent forms starting. If you have better idea I will be more than grateful if you shared it with me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Thread t = new Thread();
        t.TrySetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
```

....

and of course try,catch error handling..